# how to exclude some list properties to make data table

Tags: c#

In below utility function (list to Data Table), how can I exclude some member of list.

Like, I don't want to send the 2 properties "UniqueKey" & "PointToPointData" to the utility method below,

```
public class PointDataClone
{
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<PointToPointData> PointToPointData { get; set; }
}
```

Utility Function,

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> iList)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = propertyDescriptorCollection[i];
            Type type = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType;

            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);

            dataTable.Columns.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, type);
        }
        object[] values = new object[propertyDescriptorCollection.Count];
        foreach (T iListItem in iList)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = propertyDescriptorCollection[i].GetValue(iListItem);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: you might be able to use data annotations in your class and test those in your for loop and continue when you encounter properties that have these annotations.

Comment: excellent idea, any sample code

Comment: When using : dataTable.Rows.Add(values); the array 'values' has to be in the same order as the columns in the datatable.  Value can contain the first 5 columns of the datatable if the datatable contains 8 columns.  The last 3 columns of the datatable will be filled with nulls.  Sometimes you can  get errors with the nulls if the field type doesn't allow nulls.   If UniqueKey and/or PointToPointData are in the middle of the array your code has issues.   I usually use following dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {input1, input2, input5, input6, input10});

Comment: the order is taken care

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create an attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DontShowMe : Attribute
{
}
```

You can then use the attribute to annotate your class

```
public class PointDataClone
{
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    [DontShowMe]
    public string UniqueKey { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [DontShowMe]
    public List<PointToPointData> PointToPointData { get; set; }
}
```

and modify your function to query the attributes. You will need an additional using statement

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

add this line to your loop

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);

// test attribute to see if it is shown
if (propertyDescriptor.Attributes.Contains(new DontShowMe())) continue;

dataTable.Columns.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, type);
```

You will now have to deal with the fact that your object will have more properties than the datatable has columns. I will leave it to you to manage that little detail.

Hope this helps,

Marc

Comment: what if I want to exclude UniqueKey for one type  and want to include for another type?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below Code.
I passed list of string to exclude properties name.
See below Code.

```
 public static DataTable ToDataTableVendorExp<T>(List<T> items,List<string> ExcludeColumnName)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(a => a.PropertyType != typeof(System.Object)).Cast<PropertyInfo>().ToArray();
        List<int> lstIgnoreIndex = new List<int>();
        int colIndex = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {

            //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
            var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
            //Setting column names as Property names
            string dtcolumname = prop.Name;
            //check if property name of list dont need to export then ignore.
            if (ExcludeColumnName != null && ExcludeColumnName.IndexOf(dtcolumname) >= 0)
            {
                lstIgnoreIndex.Add(colIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(DisplayNameRptAttribute)))
                {
                    var attrvalue = (DisplayNameRptAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameRptAttribute));
                    dtcolumname = attrvalue.GetName();
                }

                dataTable.Columns.Add(dtcolumname, type);
            }
            colIndex++;
        }
        //if ignore 3 properties out of 10 then only 7 required.
        int totlaproplength = Props.Length;
        if (lstIgnoreIndex.Count > 0)
            totlaproplength = totlaproplength - lstIgnoreIndex.Count;

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[totlaproplength];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                if (lstIgnoreIndex.IndexOf(i) >= 0)
                    continue;
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                if (Props[i].ToString() == "System.DateTime Date")
                {
                    values[i] = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", (Props[i].GetValue(item, null)));
                }
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```